# Alternative option for displaying data in real time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

We have a ASP.NET web app that needs to display data in real time or as best s and we are currently using AJAX and web services but this causes performance issues because number of clients is getting bigger and bigger. Data is being pooled every 5-10 seconds and when this is multiplies by 1000+ clients it can make data retrieval quite slow.

Comment: It is better that data retrieval is not tied to client queries. I suggest to use caching instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to try using [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to handle your real-time data needs. From the site:

> ASP.NET SignalR is a new library for ASP.NET developers that makes it incredibly simple to add real-time web functionality to your applications. What is "real-time web" functionality? It's the ability to have your server-side code push content to the connected clients as it happens, in real-time.
>
> You may have heard of WebSockets, a new HTML5 API that enables bi-directional communication between the browser and server. SignalR will use WebSockets under the covers when it's available, and gracefully fallback to other techniques and technologies when it isn't, while your application code stays the same.
>
> SignalR also provides a very simple, high-level API for doing server to client RPC (call JavaScript functions in your clients' browsers from server-side .NET code) in your ASP.NET application, as well as adding useful hooks for connection management, e.g. connect/disconnect events, grouping connections, authorization.

Answer (score 1):

Try one or more of the following:

Caching – can you consider store your application data in memory for some time. That will reduce the impact on the database server.

HTML 5 Server Side events – Using Server Side Events you can actually notify clients (push data instead of pooling) when change happens. You would essentially need one ASP.NET event handler (ashx page) that pushes requests and some JS code on the client side.

Check out [this](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_internet/displaying-real-time-data-using-html5-and-asp.net.htm) article for more details and code examples on Server Side Events.